# iOS: SSL error - page not loading in WKWebView but loads in Safari

Tags: ios, ssl, safari, wkwebview

In the app I'm working on, I need to handle 3-D Secure redirects from our payment service provider. These redirects point to a web page of the card issuer that is shown in a `WKWebView` to the user in the app.

This works all the time except one case where the `WKWebView` doesn't load for https://3dsecure.csas.cz/ and fails with the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain
Code=-1200
"An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."
```

What's interesting is that the same URL loads with no problems in Safari or in `SFSafariViewController`. Even the server's certificate is okay:

[image: Safari screenshot - certificate for 3dsecure.csas.cz]

I've tried to play around with `NSAppTransportSecurity` settings in app's `Info.plist` file, specifically enable `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` and `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` but it does have no effect.

Answer (score 18):

### Forward Secrecy

It turns out that the server for `3dsecure.csas.cz` does not support Forward Secrecy: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=3dsecure.csas.cz&s=194.50.240.77

Perfect forward secrecy is required by `App Transport Security` in iOS9 and above for all app connections, [including webviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31065204/ios-9-are-webviews-exempt-from-the-app-transport-security-exceptions-ats) (not including Safari, however)

#### ATS Debugging

Running the following command in Terminal runs ATS diagnostics and tells more about the problem and how to solve it:

```
/usr/bin/nscurl --ats-diagnostics --verbose https://3dsecure.csas.cz
```

#### ATS Exception in the app

Allowing the webview in the app to connect to a specific server that does not support forward secrecy could be done by adding the following in the `Info.plist` file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>3dsecure.csas.cz</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

### Not future-proof

This exception needs to be added for every single domain that does not support forward secrecy. Unfortunately, It's impossible to know all the 3-d secure servers in advance as they come as redirects from the payment provider.

What I don't know is if not requiring forward secrecy could be set for any domain, globally, and just within a specific webview, without affecting the whole app.

Comment: Will give you a bounty because this will save me a lot of time.

Comment: Note: I remember contacting the tech support of the CSAS but I believe I never heard back from them. Feel free to contact them too so workarounds like this won't be needed in the future.