# React Native Webview 3D secure pages don't open on iOS devices

Tags: ios, react-native, ssl, webview, 3d-secure

I'm having a strange issue with RN Webview. I need to open the payment page with Webview on my app, and when I select the 3D secure payment option, all banks show me an error page. This only happens on iOS devices, everything works fine on all browsers and on Android devices.

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42645946/ios-ssl-error-page-not-loading-in-wkwebview-but-loads-in-safari) solution on Stackoverflow but it didn't work for me. I tried the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` key, I also added the bank URL's as `NSExceptionDomains`, with `NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy` key set to false.

One thing I noticed is that when I run the `/usr/bin/nscurl --ats-diagnostics --verbose https:{bankUrl}` command, I see the only Failing situation is when the `NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion` value is TLSv1.3. When I check the payment page on browser, I see the used protocol is TLS 1.3, so I thought this could be the issue.

I tried to set `NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion` to TLSv1.3, but then I get the `an ssl error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made` error. I'm out of ideas here, what should I do?

Comment: Even if I did, unfortunately I have no idea what the solution is, it was a while ago and I left the company :(